# Why `shortest_paths` function from `igraph` returns results different from the solution i got manually?

Tags: r, igraph, dijkstra

I would like to calculate the shortest path (according to Dijkstra's algorithm) between the node A and all the other nodes in the following graph

[image]

Manually, I obtaineed the following table:

[image]

So according to my calculations, the shortest paths between A and all the other nodes are depicted in the following picture:

[image]

Anyway, I wrote a code to obtain this result but I returned a different situation. What am I doing wrong? This is the code:

```
library(igraph)

graph <- graph.formula(
  A -+ B,
  B -+ C,
  C -+ D,
  D -+ E,
  A -+ D,
  B -+ D,
  B -+ E
)


E(graph)$weight <- c(3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 1, 4)

shortest_paths <- shortest_paths(graph, from = "A", mode = "out", weights = E(graph)$weight)

for (i in 1:vcount(graph)) {
  if (i != which(V(graph)$name == "A")) {
    target_vertex <- V(graph)$name[i]
    shortest_path <- shortest_paths$vpath[[i]]
    path_weight <- shortest_paths$vpath[[i]]$weight
    cat("Shortest path from A to", target_vertex, ": ")
    cat(paste(shortest_path, collapse = " -> "), "\n")
    cat("Weight:", path_weight, "\n\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: Edges are probably not indexed the way assumed, so those weights are assigned to `A->B A->D B->C B->D B->E C->D D->E`  accordingly, check `as_data_frame(graph)` . There's also one edge missing, but that might be intentional.

Comment: @margusl You are right! With
`>dput(as_data_frame(graph))` I obtain:
`structure(list(from = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D"), to = c("B", 
"D", "C", "D", "E", "D", "E"), weight = c(3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 1, 4
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 7L))`
But how is it possible? How could I fix this problem?

Comment: You could use slightly different notation, i.e.  `graph_from_literal(A -+ B:C:D, B -+ C:D:E, C -+ D, D -+ E)` returns `A->B A->C A->D B->C B->D B->E C->D D->E`.   In both cases edges are ordered by starting nodes.  When dealing with edge attributes, building graphs from dataframes or matrices is likely more robust method.

Comment: In my opinion this behaviour of `graph_from_literal()` is quite confusing. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/824